# Structure query does not match result type

Tags: sql, postgresql

I tried to create a stored procedure with the following code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_paycheck(empl_id varchar, lmt integer, offst integer)
RETURNS TABLE(
        request_id varchar
        , nip varchar
        , email varchar
        , request_date timestamp with time zone 
        , salary_month date
        , salary_year float
        , status integer
        , created_time timestamp with time zone)
language plpgsql stable
as $function$
        BEGIN       
        return query

                select
                trp.request_id
                ,e.nip
                ,trp.email
                ,trp.request_date
                ,trp.salary_month
                ,date_part('year', trp.salary_month)
                ,trps.status
                ,trps.created_time
                from tr_request_paycheck trp
                join tr_request_paycheck_status trps on trps.request_id = trp.request_id
                join ms_empl e on e.empl_id = trp.empl_id
                    where case 
                            when $1 is not null and $1 <> '' then trp.empl_id = $1
                            else true
                        end


                group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
                LIMIT $2
                OFFSET $3;

        end;
    $function$;
```

Whenever I execute it, I get an error

> Structure query does not match result type

even though I match all the type from my table.

Can anyone help me fix the issue?

Comment: Would need to see the ddl for the tables/columns being used. in the select.  Additionally, you may need to explicitly cast one or more of the columns to the desired datatype if all values returned are null.  Seems really odd to be storing year as a float.  date_part year doesn't seem like it would return float data type.. it doesn't it returns ; it returns type double precision.  also seems odd that salary month would be a date datatype...

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/xVgOJ first table and the second http://imgur.com/a/GVImk

Comment: i just realized that the data type of created_time is different, its suppose to be timestamptz not time
am i correct?

Comment: That's the primary concern.  I'd also be concerned with possibly `ms_empl.nip` I don't know its data type and possibly the `Salary_year` as it's a float from a double precision result in the view.  Year in my book should be int data; I'd never want to see/allow a decimal there.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up with:

- Issue is with created_Time(timestamp w/ tz)  in function vs created_Time(Time(8)) in SQL time vs date/time (as you mentioned in comment)
- Possible issue with SQL ms_empl.nip(undefined) vs function nip(varchar)
- odd name salary_month for a date data type (maintenance concern)
- salary_year Double Precision SQL vs float in function why float? why not int?  I wouldn't want to see(accidentally allow)a decimal in my year...  so cast as int?

.

```
+---------------+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------+------------------+
|    Column     |     Function Expects     |               You Passed                | Which is of type |
+---------------+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------+------------------+
| request_id    | varchar                  | tr_request_paycheck.request_ID          | Varchar(255)     |
| nip           | varchar*                 | ms_empl.nip                             | Undefined*        |
| email         | varchar                  | tr_request_paycheck.email               | varchar(255)     |
| request_date  | timestamp with time zone | tr_request_paycheck.request_date        | timestamptz(28)  |
| salary_month  | date                     | tr_request_paycheck.salary_month        | Date             |
| salary_year   | float                    | date_part('year', trp.salary_month)     | Double Precision |
| status        | integer                  | tr_request_paycheck_Status.status       | Int4             |
| created_time  | timestamp with time zone*| tr_request_paycheck_Status.Created_Time | Time(8)(          |
+---------------+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------+------------------+
```